# I want to start using TEX to write up assignments and labs

Tags: installing, editors, distributions

I want to start coding in my assignments and lab reports in TEX (I'm not sure that's the correct software name) as they look more professional.

The only TEX knowledge I have is writing mathematical equations like:

```
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$
```

As for coding experience goes, I have done programming in C and C++ before.

My question is then:

What program or online editor is the best to use? and where can I find some good tutorials?

(I'm sorry that my Tag does not relate to what I'm asking, I don't know what the appropriate tag is.)

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean plain TeX or LaTeX or...? You need [an editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) and a distribution such as TeX Live or MikTeX. Strictly speaking, the editor is optional. You can use any plain text editor. But a TeX one is easier.

Comment: I think I would like to use LaTeX to compile my work. I found a website called overleaf which I think is some sort of editor. Is this good enough for what I want to do ? and does it use LaTeX ?

Comment: Overleaf or Papeeria are on-line editors+compilers. Is a excellent way  to test how  LaTeX work without messing with installation/configuration   knowing nothing about LaTeX. If work on-line is not a priority for you, or you are limited in some way using on-line tools, then install TeX Live and some  text/LaTeX editors (LyX, Gummi, TeXworks,  ...nano, vim. emacs....) and take your time to decide what sytem do you like to edit and compile, i.e., nano + `pdflatex file.tex` in a Linux terminal, or simply Lyx  ( internally call to `pdflatex` by default) or TeXworks but using `arara`, or ... or ...